# Sum subtotals within dynamic ranges vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way for sum subtotals.
 subtotals image

[image]

As you could see in the pic. i have a column with key codes that allows me to use Find. for looking through all values (in column o) and selecting those that belong to its corresponding section.
The issue is that because my poor knowledge in VBA, I was trying long without success. The time has come for asking for some help.
Here as follows some hints about what I was doing/trying.
As you can see here, I was trying with Find. for looking values in column "O". After that, I was not capable to select them for sum.

```
Sub Mod9x()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant, arrElem1 As Variant
    Dim firstAddress As String, c As Range, rALL As Range
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim i, j As Long, r As Range, d As Double

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Valeurs")
    lr = sh1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 15 To lr
        With sh1
            On Error Resume Next
            For Each cell In sh1.Cells(i, 5)
                arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ")
                For Each arrElem1 In arr
                    If Len(arrElem1) = 15 Then
                        lResult1 = arrElem1
                        Set Findv1 = Range("E15:E3000").Cells.Find(What:=lResult1, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          After:=Range("E15"), SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not Findv1 Is Nothing Then
                            With Findv1
                                Set c = .Find(Findv1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                                    Set rALL = c
                                    firstAddress = c.Address
                                    Do

                                        Set rALL = Union(rALL, c)
                                        sh1.Range(c.Address).Activate
                                        Set c = .FindNext(c)

                                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                                End If

                                .Activate
                                If Not rALL Is Nothing Then c.Offset(, 10).Select
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.sum (Selection)

                                sh1.Cells(Findv1, 15) = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Selection)

                            End With


                        End If
                    End If
                Next arrElem1
            Next cell
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Really grateful for any support.

Additional code for Key values finding:

```
    Sub x()

Dim r As Range, d As Double

For Each r In Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If UBound(Split(r, ".")) = 3 Then
        d = d + r.Offset(, 10).Value
        r.Offset(, 10).Value = d
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

[image: Result after lines of code]

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the bits circled in red? Why don't you look for Sub-total in the left hand column and base it on that?

Comment: Hi SJR, i would like if possible to avoid the use of subtotals, and have the results from operations instead. Thanks

Comment: What I meant was, could you not just the actual text "Subtotal" to look for the values you want to sum?

Comment: That text shouldn't be there in final version, it is only as info. I'm just want to say to excel stop once it arrives to a different type of number in column "E", and sum those found before. In part the code might be:

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - add it to your question if it helps. This is confusing - your text refers to looking in column O but your code appears to be searching col E. Are you looking for text which consists of four two digit numbers separated by dots?

Comment: Ok, i'll. Yes, they are numbers separated by dots.

Comment: So to repeat my earlier question are you looking to add the text in red circles? What exactly is the problem with your code - be as specific as possible?

Comment: I would like to obtain by vba, partials sums in column "O" in rows where numbers are separated by two dots in column "E", from values corresponding with three dots separated numbers (column "E"). The sum shall restart every time code find a two dots separated number in column "E". Really appreciate any help.

Comment: I see now that I provided that second bit of code earlier, but you never acknowledged it or responded to the thread, which does not provide much incentive to respond again.

Comment: Yes, you provided it! i was off during some time, and the issue has returned again. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is just a slight variation on the code above. Let me know how you get on.

```
Sub x()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, d As Double

For Each r1 In Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    For Each r2 In r1
        If UBound(Split(r2, ".")) = 3 Then
            d = d + r2.Offset(, 10).Value
        End If
    Next r2
    r1(1).Offset(-1) = Left(r1(1), 8)
    r1(1).Offset(-1, 10) = d
    d = 0
Next r1

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok SJR, first of all, thanks so much for your support! I've used the lines of your code, and, would you please see above within the question? I've added a pic for explaining what the code has gave me. In red, the macro result, and in blue what i need to achieve. Do you think i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your starting data as set out in your top picture? If you run the macro twice this could happen, though am confused by the zeros.

Comment: Marked in red has appeared after first run. Data set starts in row 15, with headtitle **00.10.10**.

Comment: So are you saying that the headings "00.10.10"  and "00.10.20" are already there? I had assumed that you wanted the macro to add them.

Comment: Sorry, i know i'm not good with explanations. Column "E" have all codes 00.10.10, 00.10.20... and so. I just need the *partial* sum of those separated by three dots, placed in column "O" of corresponding two separated (headtitile) code (00.10.10...) row.

Comment: Already it works! after copy removal and addressing to right cells. Thanks a lot SJR!!!